# In Cloud Firestore how to make an, create only once security rule

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I just stared migrate to Cloud Firestore and wonder about this security rule.
In the Firebase realtime databas this rule:

> Evaluates to true if one operand in the rules expression is true.
>
> In this example, we can write as long as old data or new data does not
>   exist. In other words, we can write if we're deleting or creating
>   data, but not updating data.
>
> ".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()"

I´m trying to replicate in the Cloud Firestore like

> ```
> match /USER_ID/{Id} {
>   allow create: if resource.data.id != exist
>   allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
>   }
> ```

What I want is that if the `Document` exist in the `USER_ID` `Collection` then the Transaction this is happening in must fail. 
But this is not working. I have read the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data) a few times but cant get it to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use the exist function, for which you need to pass it the path of the document you are testing if it exists. Below is an example of how you'd check if the document doesn't exist.

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents/ {
      match /USER_ID/{Id} {
         allow create: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/USER_ID/$(Id))
         allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried something close to this but now it works